# How does Python resolve variable conflicts in list comprehensions with 'for x in x' syntax?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm learning Python, having come from Java/C++, and have reached list comprehension.

In it is this example:

```
x = 'ABC'
codes = [ord(x) for x in x]
print(x, codes)
```

And 'ABC' [65, 66, 67] is printed.

Why is the list comprehension okay with both variables having the same name? How does it know which one to send to ord()? Is this good practice or would it be preferred to use a different variable for the iterator?

Comment: Your code converts each character in the string 'ABC' to its corresponding ASCII code and stores the codes in a list.

The list comprehension [ord(x) for x in x] is used to iterate over each character in the string x. For each character, the ord() function is applied to get its ASCII code, and the result is stored in the list codes.

Comment: I’m too lazy to write a proper answer, but here’s a link to the relevant docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries

Comment: To a first approximation, the answer is basically the same as how a function with a parameter named `x` treats that variable differently from a global variable named `x` passed as an argument. (Currently, the body of the list comprehension *is* turned into an anonymous function that gets called with the "outer" `x`--or rather, an iterator created from `x`--as an argument. That implementation detail is being changed for Python 3.12 to make list comprehensions more efficient; read [PEP 709](https://peps.python.org/pep-0709/) for more details.)

Comment: Note that whilst this is fine done deliberately to learn about scopes, it's needlessly confusing in real code.  Prefer `[ord(c) for c in x]` (since c is a char) or the like.

Answer (score 3):

The current implementation (as of Python 3.11) basically turns the list comprehension into a function to put the two different `x`s into different scopes, equivalent to

```
x = 'ABC'

def _tmp(x_itr):
    rv = []
    for x in x_itr:
        rv.append(x)
    return rv

codes = _tmp(iter(x))
```

[PEP 709](https://peps.python.org/pep-0709/) outlines how the temporary function will be "inlined" to improve performance; this change is slated to be included in Python 3.12, to be released later this year.

---

You can use the `dis` module to see how CPython currently implements your example (via `python3 -m dis tmp.py`, with comments added by me).

```
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  # Define the outer x
  1           2 LOAD_CONST               0 ('ABC')
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (x)

  # Create _tmp (see below) 
  2           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x11049b3c0, file "tmp.py", line 2>)
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            0

  # Call codes = _tmp(iter(x))
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
             12 GET_ITER
             14 PRECALL                  0
             18 CALL                     0
             28 STORE_NAME               1 (codes)

  # Print the results.
  [...]

# Actual body of _tmp
Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x11049b3c0, file "tmp.py", line 2>:
  2           0 RESUME                   0
              # rv = []
              2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
              # for x in <argument>
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                17 (to 42)
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
              # rv.append(ord(x))
             10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NULL + ord)
             22 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             24 PRECALL                  1
             28 CALL                     1
             38 LIST_APPEND              2
             40 JUMP_BACKWARD           18 (to 6)
             # return rv
        >>   42 RETURN_VALUE
```

(If you aren't familiar with the stack machine used by CPython, arguments are passed to a function by putting the function on the stack, followed by its arguments. `CALL` replaces the function and its arguments with the return value of the function, and `RETURN_VALUE` returns whatever is on the top of the stack.)

The `x` referring to `'ABC'` is only used by the code in the first part of the dump. The `x` used to iterate over that list is only used inside the code block used to create a temporary function.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the list comprehension okay with both variables having the same
> name?

Because the comprehension behaves like a function with its own scope. If instead of a comprehension you had written a classic for loop, as you intuited, you'd have problems.

> How does it know which one to send to ord()?

The x in the comprehension list has a local scope and is deleted from the memory when the comprehension is done. Check out this example:

```
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

>>> [x for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

And compare it to this:

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> mylist
[]
>>> for x in range(10):
...     mylist.append(x)
...
>>> mylist
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> x
9
```

Python doesn't "know" which value to send: it sends the value in memory to which he name "x" is linked to. If you change this value, then it will use this new value and "forget" the previous.

> Is this good practice or would it be preferred to use a different variable for the iterator?

Definitely not a good practice. Use a different name, and feel free to make it as explicit as possible, if necessary (it's not always the case). E.g. :

```
[for n in range(10)]
```

Here "n" is perfectly sufficient. You can even use '_' if you prefer, to show that it has no importance

But if you have the following dict:

```
my_dict = {"L": "John", "M": "Paul", "S": "Ringo", "H": "Georges"}
```

then explicit vars are better:

```
[name.upper() + " " + initial for initial, name in my_dict.items()]
```

is clearer than `[x.upper() + " " + y for y, x in my_dict.items()]`